# Set the type of registered Service during runtime within an action filter/message handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

```
     public class ActionFilterVersionAttribute  : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
            {
                if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Any(x => x.Key == "SetInternalVersion"))
                {
  // determine somehow that the **InternalSystem implementation** should be resolved when the controller class is instantiated with the **ISystem constructor** parameter              
                }
                else
                {
 // determine somehow that the **ExternalSystem implementation** should be resolved when the controller class is instantiated with the **ISystem constructor** parameter
                }

                base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
            }
        }
```

I have `ExternalSystem/InternalSystem with the ISystem interface.`

How can I tell autofac to inject the ExternalSystem or InternalSystem into the instantiated controller as ISystem instance depending on the string value I pass in the ActionFilter or maybe message handler.

I know I can do stuff like:

```
builder.RegisterType<InternalSystem>().As<ISystem>().Keyed<ISystem>("Internal");
```

where I can use a `func<string,ISystem>` factory to resolve the class during runtime but this is not what I want to do.

Actually I need to register the ISystem within the the action filter, but then I would need somehow to pass the container into the filter, but that is not what I want...and prolly its also not possible.

```
// Action: returns external or internal value
public string Get()
{
    return resolvedISystem.Get();
}
```

Of course I could resolve the ISystem depending on the func factory within each single action or put behavior into a base controller where I check for the header, but I really would prefer the action filter as it can be just globally registerd ONE time, but for each new controller I have to subclass the base controller.

Base controller sample with pseudo code , because the base.Request is null which needs another workaround/fix...

```
   public class BaseController : ApiController
    {

        public BaseController(Func<string, ISystem> dataServiceFactory)
        {
            string system =  base.Request.Headers.Any(x => x.Key == "SetInternalVersion") ? "internal" : "external";
            System = dataServiceFactory(system);
        }
        public ISystem System { get; set; }
    }
```

UPDATING the container is also marked as OBSOLETE by the Autofac author.

Thus I do not want to add registrations in my filter/handler and update/build the container again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should not use `ActionFilter` at all. You have a controller dependency which should be resolved properly based on the information coming from request. Here is a possible solution. You can use a static `HttpContext.Current` property in order to extract request header.

**System classes:**

```
public interface ISystem { }
public class ExternalSystem : ISystem { }
public class InternalSystem : ISystem { }
```

**SystemKeyProvider:**

```
public enum SystemKey
{
    External,
    Internal
}

public interface ISystemKeyProvider
{
    SystemKey GetSystemKey();
}

public class SystemKeyProvider : ISystemKeyProvider
{
    private const string HeaderKey = "SetInternalVersion";
    private readonly HttpRequest _request;
    public SystemKeyProvider(HttpRequest request)
    {
        _request = request;
    }

    public SystemKey GetSystemKey()
    {
        return (_request.Headers[HeaderKey] != null) ? 
            SystemKey.Internal : 
            SystemKey.External;
    }
}
```

**Controller constructor:** `ValuesController(ISystem system)`

**Autofac container registration:**

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.Request).As<HttpRequest>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<SystemKeyProvider>().AsImplementedInterfaces();

// service registration
builder.RegisterType<ExternalSystem>().Keyed<ISystem>(SystemKey.External);
builder.RegisterType<InternalSystem>().Keyed<ISystem>(SystemKey.Internal);
builder.Register(c => 
    c.ResolveKeyed<ISystem>(c.Resolve<ISystemKeyProvider>().GetSystemKey()))
    .As<ISystem>();

builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
    new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(builder.Build());
```

In this solution I created a `SystemKeyProvider` wrapper class which is responsible for providing appropriate key in order to resolve `ISystem`.

---

**Demo:**

When no `SetInternalSystem` header is present.

[image: No SetInternalSystem header is present. Fiddler]

Then the dependency is resolved as `ExternalSystem`.

[image: Then dependency is resolved as ExternalSystem]

When `SetInternalSystem` header is present.

[image: SetInternalSystem header is present]

Then the dependency is resolved as `InternalSystem`.

[image: Then dependency is resolved as InternalSystem]

Comment: 1.) I tried now a message handler updating the container, that works but that should not be done due to the Obsolete warning. 2.) I tried the func factory in an action filter adding the resolved service to request.Properties bag 3.) If your solution works, its technically the most sophisticated, I did not know about registering the current request thats really nice idea!

Comment: Great it works nice. I still upvote that answer as its a good one! Thank you.

Comment: While the answer is correct, the fact that you rely on `HttpContext.Current` is a bit flaky, as if you use Web API on top of OWIN, `HttpContext.Current` is not set. I would suggest using the `RegisterHttpRequestMessage` extension method on `ContainerBuilder`. This registers the `HttpRequestMessage` with a per-HTTP request lifetime scope. The `SystemKeyProvider` could then use it instead of `HttpContext`.

Comment: Our webapi is still old and afair no owin is used, but thanks I will check the RegisterHttpRequestMessage stuff and see how it works!

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey  I got this exception: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Test.SystemKeyProvider' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Web.HttpRequest request' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Web.HttpRequest)'. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.), ------------------------------------- I did this:            builder.RegisterHttpRequestMessage(config); instead of the HttpContext.Current. Any idea?

Comment: @Pascal Using the `RegisterHttpRequestMessage` method registers the `HttpRequestMessage` class in the container, as opposed to `HttpRequest` in your example. This means you have to change the `SystemKeyProvider` dependency from `HttpRequest` to `HttpRequestMessage`. You'll be able to access the headers with the `Headers` property.